# VSTO: How to modify first called function

Tags: vb.net, vsto, postsharp

So I have this VSTO add-in for excel, in which I want to use postSharp for diagnostics.

PostSharp requires the following code before the first called class:

```
<Log(AttributeExclude:=True)>
```

And the following code in the first called function:

```
LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = New Backends.Console.ConsoleLoggingBackend()
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157876.aspx), any startup code for the add-in should be put in the `ThisAddin_Startup` function, but if I put it there, I get an exception that a logged function was called before the backend was set. This function is said to reside in `ThisAddin.Designer.vb`, but that seems to be generated code, and I cannot find it in my Visual Studio Sollution.

Where should I put this code, to run it at startup of the Add-In?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a module initializer. See http://doc.postsharp.net/module-initializer for details.

Comment: Okay, that sounded really complicated, but it was much easier than expected :) Thank you!